# What will happen if a TCP RST is lost?

Tags: tcp, reset, unreliable-connection

As per my understanding, if a TCP RST is sent, the sender(A) closes the socket and the connection is closed at its end. Now, since the RST is lost, the intended receiver(B) is not yet aware of the RST sent. If B now tries to send more data to A, how will A react and what response is got at B?

Answer (score 0):

> As per my understanding, if a TCP RST is sent, the sender(A) closes the socket

No. The sender had already closed the socket, or maybe the connection never existed in the first place. Then something arrived for the connection, then the RST was issued. [It is possible for close to issue an RST but it is both infrequent and undesirable.]

> and the connection is closed at its end.

Already, if it ever existed.

> Now, since the RST is lost, the intended receiver(B) is not yet aware of the RST sent. If B now tries to send more data to A, how will A react and what response is got at B?

This is no different from the original situation. There is no connection for the data to be delivered to, so an RST is issued.